# Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (testdb)]

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp, junit5

I want to use Spring Data JPA in a new project. I basically followed the setup described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/.

Everything works fine, when I start the application or when I start a single test.

As soon as I start two tests together, Spring can not load the ApplicationContext in the second test, because it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (testdb)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
```

How can I avoid the second attempt to register the HikariDataSource?

This is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

    compile "com.h2database:h2"

    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6"

    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0"
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.0.0"

    testRuntime "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0"
    testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0"

    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
}
```

and the first test class

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(Application.class)
class FirstRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private FirstRepository firstRepository;
```

Using junit 4 and `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` resolves the problem, so it must be caused by the interaction of junit 5 and spring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load Spring Context for all tests once, see for example [post](http://nixmash.com/post/the-old-instancealreadyexistsexception-junit-trick) which uses `@ContextConfiguration`:

> that problem was loading the Spring Context with each test class. The
>   solution was restructuring the test classes by extending an
>   AbstractContext base class which loaded a Spring Context for all tests
>   to share, and all the Beans therein.

Comment: I already tried this (i.e. extracting a base class with the application context). It does not help.

Comment: Also it is no problem with junit 4 where I do not share the application context explicitly between the tests.

Comment: i can confirm it is working when moving @ContextConfiguration to the base class

Comment: That link is dead.  Is this behavior documented anywhere else?

Comment: @krum tell me if following link is ok https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/667